# Steam api file empty

Tags: php, steam-web-api

When I try to decode json from steam api it says

> Filename cannot be empty

Sorry if the answer is obvious I am very new to php.

```
$api_url1 =  "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=$api_key&steamid=$steamid&format=json";
$json1 = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true);
```

Both my `$api_key` and `$steamid` variables are previously defined as well.

Comment: `$api_url` is not defined here. `$api_url1` is.

Comment: oh my god lol whoops thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$api_url1 = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=". $api_key ."&steamid=". $steamid ."&format=json";
$json1 = json_decode($api_url1, true);
```

Then you can use a foreach to loop through all the results.